# 2D Convolution border handling: zero padding not working?

Tags: c++, opencv, convolution

I am doing a homework where we need to write a function which gets an image and a kernel and we have to calculate the 2d spatial convolution.
Using a gaussian kernel I get the expected result (a blurred image) but if I use instead for example an edge detection kernel [(taken from here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) I see that something isn't working properly (the image becomes very greyish).

I guess the problem is either the border handling, which should be a zero-padding but I am not totally sure if implemented it correctly or the normalization at the end.
Is there a way to display a float image (e.g. one pixel of the float has a value for 25000), because I think it always gets capped at 255 (white) if I don't use the normalization.

```cpp
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("orig.jpg",0);             // load image as grayscale
    img.convertTo(img,CV_32FC1);                        // convert to float
    cv::Mat_<float> output(img.rows,img.cols);          // create new mat with same size as source image
    output = 0;   
    // creating a kernel (here Gaussian blur)
    cv::Mat_<float> kernel(5,5);
    kernel << 1,4,6,4,1,4,16,24,16,4,6,24,36,24,6,4,16,24,16,4,1,4,6,4,1;

    int kCenterX = kernel.cols/2;
    int kCenterY = kernel.rows/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++){                 // for every row in image
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++){             // for every column in image
            for (int m = 0; m < kernel.rows; m++){      // for every row of kernel
                int mm = kernel.rows - 1 -m;            // row index of flipped kernel
                for (int n = 0; n < kernel.cols; n++){  // for every column of kernel
                    int nn = kernel.cols - 1 -n;        // column index of flipped kernel
                    // index for border handling
                    int ii = i + (m - kCenterY);
                    int jj = j + (n - kCenterX);
                    // checking if sample is still in bound of input image
                    // and if not, treat those pixels as 0 (because they won't get added to sum)
                    if (ii >= 0 && ii < img.rows && jj >= 0 && jj < img.cols)
                        output.at<float>(i,j) += img.at<float>(ii,jj) * kernel.at<float>(mm,nn);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // normalize input and output image (might be wrong, but I don't know how else I can see float images
    cv::normalize(output, output, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    cv::normalize(img, img, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    // display images
    cv::imshow("Original", img);
    cv::imshow("Convolution", output);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The image is grayish because of the normalization.  Your edge detection will produce positive, negative or zero values.  The zero values get increased to 0.5, the negative values are close to 0, the positive values are close to 1.  You are getting the correct result.  I will preface that your Gaussian Blur is not truly one as you didn't normalize by the sum of the kernel values.  If you did that, then you wouldn't need to normalize the result after you do the convolution.